# Microsoft Excel 2013 - WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML formulas

Tags: excel, xml, api-design

Trying to pull the Manufacturing cost index from an XML pull. The XML comes from https://api.eve-industry.org/system-cost-index.xml?name=Osmon

I successfully used the WEBSERVICE function in excel to create and pull the data;

```
P28 = =CONCATENATE("http://api.eve-industry.org/system-cost-index.xml?name=",Q28)
```

```
=WEBSERVICE(P28)
```

My question is, how do I used FILTERXML to pull just the Manufacturing data?
So far I have

```
=FILTERXML(P29,"//Manufacturing")
```

But it only returns a #VALUE! error. I have also tried a bunch of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this also, but it seems you want to pull out the `attribute` of the `activity` whose `name` is `Manufacturing`

So the xpath expression would be `//activity[@name="Manufacturing"]`

or maybe

`//solarsystem/activity[@name='Manufacturing']`  depending on how specific you need to be.

Both work fine on your link.